# Java regex replace String in file

Tags: java, regex

I try to replace String via regex.

Target String :

```
if (ValidationUtil.checkNullable(groupDataObject) || !groupDataObject.isNotificationEnable() ||
```

Regex

```
.*(ValidationUtil\DcheckNullable)([a-zA-Z0-9]*).*
```

Replace pattern

```
$2 == null
```

Wishful result :

```
if (groupDataObject == null || !groupDataObject.isNotificationEnable() ||
```

And it's not worked. It produce result `== null`.What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(ValidationUtil\DcheckNullable)\(([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\)
                               ^^              ^^
```

I removed `.*` and added `\(` and `\)`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC6eD4/1)

If you need to also match parentheses and dots, just include them in the character class:

```
(ValidationUtil\DcheckNullable)\(([a-zA-Z0-9().]+)\)
                                            ^^^
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qL5lI7/2)

Note that instead of `\D`, you can use the dot, just remember it should be escaped with double backslash in a Java string literal: `String pat = "(ValidationUtil\\.checkNullable)\\(([a-zA-Z0-9().]+)\\)"`

Comment: One more question. In some cases I have word construction `mAdapter.getFilter()` instead of `groupDataObject` -**ValidationUtil.checkNullable(mAdapter.getFilter())**? How to include `brackets` and `dot`?

Comment: For just `mAdapter.getFilter()` - [`(ValidationUtil\DcheckNullable)\(([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\([^()]*\))*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/qL5lI7/1) can help.

Comment: Well, KISS solution is [`(ValidationUtil\DcheckNullable)\(([a-zA-Z0-9().]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/qL5lI7/2)

Answer (score 0):

$2 is null, because there is no match for next group since the following character is **(**

`.*(ValidationUtil\.checkNullable)\(([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\).*`

Try the above pattern, it has `\(` which then skips **(** and finds the group 2 match. Also if you just want to extract `groupDataObject`, add a trailing `\)`